# Display WooCommerce Product Gallery with Swiper js Slider

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, woocommerce, swiper.js

I set up a WooCommerce Theme. Now I'm trying to visualize the Product Gallery Images on the Product images with swiper js.

I implemented the ".js" and the Styles that are needed.

But Im not quite sure where to put in which Code. Im guessing I have to manipulate the "product-image.php" inside the "WooCommerce/single-product"-Folder.

This is what I have done so far inside that File:

copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

if ( $attachment_ids ) {
    $loop       = 0;
    $columns    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 3 );
    ?>
    <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper <?php echo implode( ' ', $slider_classes ); ?>"
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <?php echo $rtl; ?>
        
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
 <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          type: "progressbar",
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
      });
    </script>
   
<?php

            foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
                $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                if ( ! $image_link )
                    continue;
                $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );
                $image_caption = esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ) );

                $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), 0, $attr = array(
                    'title' => $image_title,
                    'alt'   => $image_title
                    ) );

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<li>%s</li>', $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );

                $loop++;
            }

        ?></ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```